# Specify missing values in csv file

Tags: stata

I am writing a file to csv before reading it into Stata. How do i specify missing values in the csv file, so that when the csv is read into Stata they are automatically coded by as missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer - if values are set as `.` in the csv file, they are read into stata as missing values.

Comment: Leaving the fields empty would also work. I think that's better than using a `.` in the CSV file because many programs won't recognize the dot as a missing value indicator. Also, leaving the field empty will work for strings too.